# How to stop intent-service android

Tags: android, intentservice

Hi I am developing android application in which I am using intent service. My application is working properly only problem is that:
I install my application. Start my intent service. 
Now If I uninstall my application without stopping my intent service and if I again install application my service keep running in background.
More specifically I am working on activity recognition in android and I found this problem there.

So what i want to do

when I start my application I want to check whether my intent service already running or not. If it is running already then stop it and wait till user start it again. 
How to do this. Need Help.

Comment: Stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you never have to call stopSelf(). check the topic under Extending the IntentService class. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Thank you raghunandan for replay i will try this and let you know whether this is working or not. Thank you